# Random math quiz on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a random math quiz and I want to get new random numbers
after every click on the button.
I success to get new random numbers on every click but I still get the result of the first random numbers I got on the loading on the page

Another thing I need help to increase the score size-font every time the user enters the correct answer.
I tried to do it with 2.0em but it increases only once.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1 style="font-size: 400%">Random Math Quiz</h1>
<div id="question"></div>
<input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; font-size: 32px;">
<br><br>
<button onclick="quiz()">Enter</button>
<br><br>
Score: <div id="score">0</div>
</center>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var int1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
var int2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = int1 + " " + "+" + " " + int2;
var answer = int1 + int2;
var score=0;
function quiz() {
{
var uanswer = document.getElementById('answer').value;
      if (uanswer == answer) {
          alert("Correct");
          score=(score)+1;
          document.getElementById('score').innerHTML =score     ;
          document.getElementById("question").style.fontSize = "2.0em";
      } else {
          alert("OOPS Try Again!")
          score= (score)-5;
          document.getElementById('score').innerHTML =score   ;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: When do you change the random number? I only see you setting both values once and then never again.

Comment: i did it in the quiz() function but i delete it because it still getting the answer of the first random numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your numbers do not change, is because every time you call that `quiz` function, you did not change the original `int1` and `int2`. The whole javascript is only loaded once and and two numbers will only be set at a random number, once. Unless you fire a function to change the variables.

try this:

```
var score=0;
var int1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
var int2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
var answer = int1 + int2;
document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = int1 + " " + "+" + " " + int2;


function quiz() {
  

  var user_answer = document.getElementById('answer').value;

   if (user_answer == answer) {
          alert("Correct");
          score=(score)+1;
          document.getElementById('score').innerHTML =score     
      } else {
          alert("OOPS Try Again!")
          score= (score)-5;
          document.getElementById('score').innerHTML =score   ;
      }
  
   // you need to reset the int1, int2, and answer by generating new numbers
   int1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
   int2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
   answer = int1 + int2
   document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = int1 + " " + "+" + " " + int2;
  
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Although you had 2 questions and this post only answers 1 of both you marked this as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since int1 and int2 are outside of the function they going to have the same value.
You need to generate a new random number each time you call the function quiz().

same with the font size - you changed it only once from default to 2em when you need to increase the value every time you call quiz().

```js
var int1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
var int2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = int1 + " " + "+" + " " + int2;
var answer = int1 + int2;
var score=0;
var fontSize = 1;
function quiz() {
{
var uanswer = document.getElementById('answer').value;
      if (uanswer == answer) {
          alert("Correct");
          score=(score)+1;
          document.getElementById('score').innerHTML =score     ;
          document.getElementById("question").style.fontSize = fontSize + 'em';
          fontSize++;
          int1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;  
          int2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
          answer = int1 + int2;
      } else {
          alert("OOPS Try Again!")
          score= (score)-5;
          document.getElementById('score').innerHTML =score   ;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach? You call a function in order to reset the random values after each guess. And you store your fontSize in a variable, which you increase by 2 each time the user guesses right.

```
// intitial setup
var int1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
var int2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = int1 + " " + "+" + " " + int2;
var answer = int1 + int2;
var score=0;
var fontSize = 2;

function quiz() {
    var uanswer = document.getElementById('answer').value;
    
    if (uanswer == answer) {
          alert("Correct");
          score=(score)+1;
          document.getElementById('score').innerHTML =score;
          document.getElementById("question").style.fontSize = fontSize + ".0em";

          // increase fontSize by 2 for the next correct answer
          fontSize += 2;
    } else {
          alert("OOPS Try Again!")
          score= (score)-5;
          document.getElementById('score').innerHTML =score;
    }

    // set new values
    resetValues();
}

resetValues = () => {
    int1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    int2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = int1 + " " + "+" + " " + int2;
    answer = int1 + int2;
    score=0;
}
```